# Does Cassandra do resharding when a node stores too much data?

Tags: cassandra, sharding

All I learned is that Cassandra will do resharding when a new node joins the cluster.
Will Cassandra do resharding when a node gets too much data?
If Cassandra has the resharding strategy, how to disable it?

Answer (score 3):

> Does Cassandra do resharding when a node stores too much data?

No, it does not.  When a node stores too much data, the failure policies take over, and (usually) the node shuts down.

Adding or removing a node are the only times that partition token ranges are recalculated,  forcing data to be reassigned to other nodes.

Comment: Do you think it is valuable to mention vnodes in your answer? Then I can remove my answer.

Comment: @k_rus I suppose it's a good callout.  These days though, everyone should be using Vnodes.  In fact, token reallocation doesn't happen without it.  I'd say leave your answer, as it does help to add some definition.  I'll even give an upvote!

Answer (score 1):

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68169372/840340) by @Aaron already explains that resharding only happens during adding or removing nodes. I want to add that you can use [virtual nodes](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/architecture/archDataDistributeVnodesUsing.html), so the partitions are smaller. However, you cannot change the number vnodes on already running physical node/machine.

To use vnodes change configuration in `cassandra.yaml`:

- Remove or comment out `initial_token`
- Uncomment and set `num_tokens` to desired number of vnodes. 128 or 256 can be a good number.

Comment: Thank you for your hints! I recently studied in vnodes. And I wonder if vnode can deal with dynamic load imbalancing (such as which caused by hotspots)?